# Boot loop before gui after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

Upgraded to 18.04 today, upon restart the system got stuck in a boot loop. Not sure where to proceed from here, are there any known bugs I should be looking into? [video and screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4jfy.jpg)

Edit: further info, after realising that characters typed into the shell persisted between each loop, I determined it to be most likely graphics related. Switching to on-board graphics removed the corrupted screen flash and left me with a blackscreen to hung-initialiser loop, which I was able to alt+ctrl+f2 out of for a couple of seconds and a time in order to run "service gdm stop", which ended the loop and left me with a usable terminal on my 2nd desktop.

Examining the xorg log showed a handful of errors documented in the images added below, involving "glamor detected", "failed to load egl", and "glx error", which leads me to believe this is a problem with the graphics(not sure if card or just drivers) conflicting with the new xorg.

Will continue to troubleshoot...
[xorg logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv48x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it.

Final stage of fix ended up being using the aptitude installer to reinstall gnome-desktop, rolling back a number of dependencies to previous versions.

Prior to that, after following a guide laid out by another user, I removed a couple of libgl packages which another post advised were preventing the mesa drivers from loading properly. This was a mistake and broke the system further.

Comment: Can you say which version of gnome-desktop you installed, and which dependencies you downgraded?

Comment: I can't unfortunately, i just used the command

    'aptitude reinstall gnome-desktop'

and fiddled with it's options for dependencies until it worked.